# undefined reference to function from log4cpp library

Tags: c++, qt, undefined, log4cpp

I have another problem ...
I downloaded the log4cpp library and compiled it via Microsoft Visual Studio into a .lib-file.
Now I want to link that library into a QT Project, but whenever I call a function, such as

```
std::string initFileName = "log.properties";
log4cpp::PropertyConfigurator::configure(initFileName);
```

I get lots of errors saying

```
"undefined reference to `log4cpp::PropertyConfigurator::configure(std::string const&)'"
```

Here's the code in the project file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/log4cpp/ -llog4cppLIB
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/log4cpp/ -llog4cppD
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/log4cpp/ -llog4cppLIB

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/log4cpp/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/log4cpp/include
```

I don't know, what to do :(

Comment: Sounds like you haven't actually linked the .lib file in to your target project.

Comment: I did, the editor does suggestions, when I type e.g. log4cpp:: then it shows me all the classes and functions i can use

Answer (score 0):

If the library is compiled with Visual Studio, you should configure the project to use that same compiler instead of mingw/gcc.

Comment: So, I compiled the log4cpp library with mingw and get a .a-library, but the errors still appear :/